# Web page breaks after downloading locally

Tags: html, xampp, localhost

So I need to download a file locally for development. I don't have access to the server on which it resides. I use Chrome's save page as ("Webpage, complete").

This all works fine, but as soon as I copy those files into my XAMPP dir and start to make changes, it breaks all the JS dependencies.

Does anyone have any experience of fixing the problems caused by using the browser "save as" feature, or of downloading a file locally using some other method?

HTTTrack I tried, but the page I'm talking about is part of a form that doesn't have its own URL, so I couldn't download the page.

**EDITED** - It would be best if the original file structure could be preserved when saving assets though this is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS/JS is not saved when you do Save As, you are only downloading the HTML page. You need to look at the source and download any referenced .css or .js, and fix the paths in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get access to the source file for development. When you use Save As (or any kind of save from any browser), you aren't downloading the source php/perl files; instead you're downloading the html output they produce.

Comment: I'm aware of this. I don't need the PHP, only the front-end (HTML, CSS, JS, Images)